# bash script grep output of a command

Tags: bash, grep

I am writing a bash script. I have a phonebook command which list out user profile details (a long list). I would like to grep the DomainAddress attribute in that command.

Phonebook command:

```bash
/a/b/bin/phonelookup -u $username
```

Above command returns:

```
Employee Name = Billy
Employee ID    = 123
DomainAddress  = billy@something.com
Contact        = xxx
```

I am able to print the phonebook command into a file and do a grep but it will be extra step. Is there any straight forward straight to do so?

My trial:

```
/a/b/bin/phonelookup -u $username > file.txt
grep -oP "DomainAddress  = \K(.*)" file.txt
```

Comment: `/a/b/bin/phonelookup -u $username | grep …`

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply. This works.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solution here, you can e.g. use awk or cut in one single command to get the desired output:

```bash
/a/b/bin/phonelookup -u $username | grep DomainAddress | awk '{print $3}'
```

Returns:
`billy@something.com`

Comment: You could combine grep and awk in a single call to awk...

Comment: Haha ofc! Impress us (:

Comment: As a loose rule of thumb, try to never chain `grep/sed/awk/perl` commands in a pipeline. Each is a regex engine, so it's redundant... though on small datasets, it really shouldn't matter. Just never do it in a loop over a big file.  Here,  `/a/b/bin/phonelookup -u $username | awk '/DomainAddress/{print $3}'` does the same thing without spawning another process.

Comment: grep isn't, but egrep or grep -E is, right?